bfg/assembly in sbt console not packaging the bfg .jar file
morning/afternoon/evening guys,
I am trying to compile the bfg bfg-1.11.9-SNAPSHOT-master-21d2115.jar file through the sbt console using the bfg/assembly command, however, the packaging seems to not work around the testing phase. I am following the instructions in BUILD.md, https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner. Last few lines of the log after the assembly command shows:
BFG run is complete! When ready, run: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
[info] - should be cleaned by removing the file with the duplicate FileName, leaving the folder
[info] Run completed in 10 seconds, 36 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 17
[info] Suites: completed 3, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 16, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 TEST FAILED ***
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         com.madgag.git.bfg.cli.MainSpec
[error] (bfg / Test / test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 94 s (01:34), completed 10 Apr. 2024, 6:15:58 pm
>....>....>....>....Caught exception running shutdown hook: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to join thread Thread[sbt-console0-ui-thread,5,main] after 1 second
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Unable to join thread Thread[sbt-console0-ui-thread,5,main] after 1 second

I have the latest version of java, however the .jar file was never packaged. Checked a few forums but haven't found a relevant solution yet.
Has anyone else experienced this and managed a resolution?
